# Bamboo deploy using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, deployment, bamboo

When trying to Deploy IIS content files using powershell, I am seeing the following error:

> Failing task since return code of [powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass
>   -Command /bin/sh file.ps1

We are trying to deliver web content (several web service folders) and a set of associated web.config files to an IIS server using a powershell scrpt. The script and config files are stored in SCM (Stash) and pulled across as part of a checkout task in Bamboo which are then published as artifacts to the bamboo deploy job.
The deploy job is failing.
Does anyone know the correct way to set this up both in the Bamboo Deploy job or on the Windows Server?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does /bin/sh come from? Looks like it's attempt to execute a Linux / Unix shell script.

Comment: Yes you are right - what I want is for the powershell script to be executed on the Windows box not a shell.
The bamboo deploy task is a Script object and the Run as Powershell script is ticked. The script file that is an artifact from the code checkout is entered in the Script file field and arguments are passed in.
I do not know why it is erroring with a reference to /bin/sh.

Comment: Incidentally, the output from the Bamboo log shows:
Beginning to execute external process for build 'Deployment of 'release-9' on 'dev_server1''
 ... running command line: 
/bin/sh service_deploy.ps1 -zip Content.zip -fileroot C:\services -env Dev1
 ... in: /u01/app/bamboo/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/4292609-3211266
 ... using extra environment variables:

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to resolve this issue in future, I resolved this issue by installing a Bamboo agent onto the Windows Server.
This means that the powershell script gets checked out onto the Windows server as part of the deploy job (using the Sourcecode checkout task) and so can then be run as powershell rather than the Bamboo local agent which is running on a Linux box trying to run the powershell script as a linux shell.
The only other issue that had to be overcome was ssl certs needed to be installed into the JKS (cacerts) file on the Windows Server (where the remote agent is running) as we have Bamboo running over https.